# Reinstalling MacOS "disk with mount point required" error

Tags: macos, disk-utility, monterey

I'm trying to install MacOS Monterey on an iMac from a USB installer image, and it proceeds through copying files to reboot, then comes up with this error:

```
Disk with mount point required
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I have tried Disk Utility/First aid on the drive.

[image]